# Is there any relation between Sanskrit 'kalam' of Kalamasutra and Arabic 'al-kalam'?

Tags: etymology, arabic, sanskrit

[In this text, acknowledged by both Theravada and Mahayana traditions as sacred](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalama_Sutta), Buddha gives his speech to Kalamas. According to the dictionaries, the primal Sanskrit meaning of the word कलम (kalama) is ' a thief', which, supposedly, is not the case, since by Kalams in the buddhist text they traditionally mean the inhabitants of [Kesaputta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kesaputta).

The original Sanskrit form is कालामसूत्र (Kālāmasūtra), with a long [a], but the vowel length is irrelevant to the purpose of the question, since a) the vowel length in Arabic is grammatical, not (primary) phonetic, as it is in Sanskrit, and b) in a case of cross-linguistic interaction (e.g. via a third language or more) the quality/quantity of vowels is a subject to change.

My question is; can there be any linguistic parallels between Arabic [كلام](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilm_al-Kalam) (kalam) and the addressees of Buddha's word? The similarity between the two could be more than just a phonetic coincidence, since the two words are not just pronounced more or less alike, they also mean more or less similar concepts.

The questions seems to be not so easy to answer considering some similarities in the description of the Kalam teaching in Islam (which was first mentioned as early as in 8th century) and the essence of the suttra, since both the sutra and the philosophical doctrine emphasise the importance of following rational reasoning and discourse rather than authorities or any other sources of disputable accuracy. Given the facts of existence of [Pan-Eurasian fabulae of Barlaam & Josaphat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barlaam_and_Josaphat), recorded from Japan to Ethiophia and further to Portugal, this question can be not so easy to answer at all.

Comment: [According to Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%AE#Sanskrit) there are three homonymous words in Sanskrit for `कलम`. 1 = rice, from a root meaning "to sound", 2 = writing reed, from Greek, 3 = thief, with no origin listed. Also [according to Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85), Arabic `كلام` comes from `كلم`, to speak, which comes from the triliteral root `ك ل م`, related to speech. Arabic also has `قلم` borrowed from the same Greek source as the 2nd Sanskrit homonym.

Comment: These three are all kalama- with short a in all three syllables. The name of the Kālāmasūtra has long ā in the first two syllables. Kālāma is the name of the tribe to whom the Buddha is supposed to have directed his sermon. I cannot see any semantic link between this tribal name and the Semitic root k-l-m “to speak”.

Comment: Let me just make it more clear, do you suppose the Sanskrit word was borrowed from Arabic, or vice versa? And what do you think about the time gap between the time of Buddha and the first attestation of Arabic, almost a thousand years later?

Comment: It becomes a recurring tendency, whenever asked a question about your answer, you accuse those who asked it of bigotism and illiteracy. Are we here to find out the truth, or to make groundless accusations?

Comment: Dr Dion Peoples (a specialist in Buddhism, not linguistics) has written a paper, 'Kalam and the Kalama Sutta', which you can find on academia.edu. Read footnote one to see how modern scholars in the field of religious studies react to this sort of 'etymological determinism'!

Comment: Thank you for the reference. The problem with academia.edu is that anybody can post there. There is no way that this rubbish would be accepted by a refereed academic journal. As is clear from footnote 1, it was actually rejected by at least two periodicals.

Comment: @Yellow Sky: nope, you are making it not more clear,  but rather less interesting instead. And you have not read my question nor the tags properly. Besides, there are examples of words surviving civilizations via borrowings (e.g. Latin 'asunus' => English 'ass' (= donkey) from Sumerian and Akkadian).

Comment: @fdb: a status of a publishing organisation has nothing to do with a quality of research.

Comment: Not as such, but when an author gets rejected by refereed journals and then lashes out at his/her critics as purveyors of "etymological determinism", then that ought to ring warning bells.

Comment: What really ought to ring warning bells is a thinking of broader scientific phenomenom within a small magick box of bigotism.

Comment: According to his blurb on the academia site, Mr Peoples is “formerly a Staff-Sergeant in the US Air Force, as an Intelligence Analyst (1992-2002), turned Theravada Buddhist monk”. He is clearly a firm adherent of the principle that “les voyelles ne font rien, et les consonnes fort peu de chose”.

Comment: Is the French phrase his own sayng? Or are there any facts proving that each and everyone of the articles he mentiones are entirely wrong?

Comment: It is famously attributed to Voltaire. For the benefit of those with no sense of humour I add that it is ironic. It is a parody of a certain sort of pseudo-linguistics of which Peoples's paper is a particularly blatant example.

Comment: I wanted to make it more clear for myself, not for you, still my question remains without an answer.

Comment: "k-l-m" is a typical Arabic triconsonantal root with the general meaning of speaking and words, Arabic "word", "conversation", and "to speak" are derived from it, it is very improbable that such an important word of the basic vocabulary can be borrowed into Arabic. Besides, AFAIK it is not attested in Akkadian, Phoenician or other ancient Semitic languages that existed in the times of Buddha. A Wanderwort is a word that appears in several languages across time and space, not just in two. There seem to be no mediator languages that can fill the time gap. And Wanderwort is spelled with **A**.

Comment: Well said, Yellow Sky.

Comment: @fdb: 'it is' = what? And his paper is not about linguistics, I think he didn't aim it as such. And for the benefit of those with no sense of humour I add that it is wOnderwort, not 'Wandetwort', nor 'wunderwart'.

Comment: @Yellow Sky: C 'ansu' in any Sumerian dictionary ;-)

Comment: I know about the English 'ass' and Sumerian 'ansu', but there are lots of other languages that have a similar word, which is not the case with the 'kalama' of your question. How is the Sumerian 'ansu' related to 'kalama'? If there exist some Wanderwörter, it doesn't mean that 'kalama' is also a Wanderwort. Have you considered the possibility that it's just a coincidence? Like Latin and Malaysian have almost the same words that means 'two', 'duo' and 'dua' respectfully. Maybe this is also a Wanderort?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of Arabic al-Kalama being survivors of Buddhistic tradition under Muslim rule?

Comment: Have you ever heard of [parallelomania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelomania)?

Comment: Have you ever heard about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_in_Iran?